# Data type mismatch on a join using dates

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I have a function, *lastday*, that returns the last day of a given month. Code below...

```
Function lastday(dteAny As Date) As Date
lastday = DateSerial(Year(dteAny), Month(dteAny) + 1, 1) - 1
End Function
```

I am attempting to run a query you see below..

```
Select cc.cred_id,  lastday(dateadd("m", 5, date())) as [due], 
lastday(dateadd("m", 36, a.activity_date)) as [report]

from cred_core as cc

inner join activity as a on (a.cred_id = cc.cred_id and a.activity_type = 
"recred sent" and lastday(dateadd("m", 5, date())) = lastday(dateadd("m", 
36, a.activity_date)) )
```

I get an error alerting me of a data type mismatch on the second half of the join, where I use the lastday function.

I tried surrounding the lastday function with the # delimeters hoping that it would convert it to something it could actually compare, but I assume those delimeters don't work on functions?

Any idea what I can do to solve this problem? activity_date is, of course, a date/time data type. Using Access 2007-2013.

Answer (score 0):

Those type of joins are not supported in Access. Try to set the dates in criteria.

```
SELECT cc.cred_id,  lastday(DateAdd("m", 5, Date())) As [due],
       lastday(DateAdd("m", 36, a.activity_date)) As [report]
FROM cred_core as cc INNER JOIN activity As a ON (a.cred_id = cc.cred_id)
WHERE a.activity_type = "recred sent" 
  AND lastday(DateAdd("m", 5, date())) = lastday(DateAdd("m", 36, a.activity_date));
```